# Is this simple inequality true under the given conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Consider two sets $L$ and $L^{\prime}$ such that:

1. $i\notin L$;
2. $i\notin L^{\prime}$;

some function $\nu:\{L,L^{\prime},L\cup\{i\},L^{\prime}\cup\{i\}\}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ (where $\mathbb{R}^+$ denotes non-negative reals) such that:

3. $\nu(L)\leqslant\nu(L^{\prime})$;
4. $\nu(L\cup\{i\})\leqslant\nu(L^{\prime}\cup\{i\})$;
5. $\nu(L)\leqslant\nu(L\cup\{i\})$;
6. $\nu(L^{\prime})\leqslant\nu(L^{\prime}\cup\{i\})$;
7. $\nu(L)\leqslant\nu(L\cup\{i\})-\eta$, where $\eta\geqslant0$;

**Then, is the following *statement* true?**

*If Conditions 1 to 7 hold, then $\nu(L\cup\{i\})-\eta\leqslant\nu(L^{\prime})$*.

If possible, be so kind to include a brief proof (or a sketch of it). If the statement is true only under some additional (or alternative!) restrictions, please be so kind to state them. If it is false, please disprove it. If the problem is not well-defined or some additional information is missing, let me know!

Thank you all very much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\nu(L)=\nu(L'\cup \{i\})$, then all of the inequalities become equalities and $\eta=0$. So assume $\nu(L)<\nu(L'\cup \{i\})$: then without loss of generality, we can shift and rescale $\nu$ so that $\nu(L)=0$ and $\nu(L'\cup\{i\})=1$. Write $a=\nu(L')$, $b=\nu(L\cup\{i\})$, $x=b-\eta$. Then the information given amounts to

$$\begin{gather}
0\leq a\leq 1 \\
0\leq b\leq 1 \\
0\leq x \leq b\text{.}
\end{gather}$$

Does this information imply $x\leq a$, or do there exist values $x$, $a$, and $b$ satisfying these hypotheses such that $x>a$? You may want to draw a [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please elaborate a bit more on the two questions at the end of your answer?

Comment: Hasse diagrams are useful for determining whether some inequalities imply others in partially ordered sets; consequently, they can help you determine whether the assumed inequalities imply $x\leq a$. On the other hand, if you can find real numbers $(a,b,x)$ such that $0\leq a<x\leq b\leq 1$, then you've found a counterexample to your statement.

Comment: If you can *prove* that $\nu(L\cup \{i\})-\eta>\nu(L')$ is impossible for all data satisfying your hypotheses, then you've shown $\nu(L\cup \{i\})-\eta\leq \nu(L')$.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm so happy I was just able to prove so. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.